# Sound not playing when form is reopened

Tags: vb.net, audio

Hello everyone I have a bingo game made in vb.net. I have sounds recorded in my D: folder. I play it every time a digit and letter is drawn, but whenever I close the game form and then from the menu, start a new game again, the sound doesn't play anymore.The program does go through the sound function I made though but it doesn't play the sounds. Here are my codes:

```
Sub sound()
    If lblletter.Text <> "" And lblNumber.Text <> "" And lbllang.Text = "English" Then
        Dim sound As String = "D:\BINGO BONANZA\ENGLISH\" + lblletter.Text + " " + lblNumber.Text + ".wav"
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(sound) Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(sound, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        Else
            MsgBox("No sound file for this")
        End If
    ElseIf lblletter.Text <> "" And lblNumber.Text <> "" And lbllang.Text = "English" Then
        Dim sound As String = "D:\BINGO BONANZA\FILIPINO\" + lblletter.Text + " " + lblNumber.Text + ".wav"
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(sound) Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(sound, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        Else
            MsgBox("No sound file for this")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It will never enter the else if block, because it has the same conditions as the first if.  Also, put a breakpoint in there and see what is going on.  Step through it line by line and see if anything jumps out at you.

Comment: I have already solved my problem.. It doesn't have to do anything with my codes. :)

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues you can fix... Your lbllang.Text is the same for both statements. I think you ment "English" for the first and "Filipino" for the last. I have provided some changes you can do... I dont see how you would even get anything from this because the both statements would be true and you are saying if it equals this do this and the elseif is doing the same thing...?

```
 Private Sub sound()
   If lblletter.Text <> "" And lblNumber.Text <> "" And lbllang.Text = "English" Then
    Dim sound As String = "D:\BINGO BONANZA\ENGLISH\" + lblletter.Text + " " + lblNumber.Text + ".wav"
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(sound) Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(sound, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    Else
        MsgBox("No sound file for this")
    End If
  Else
    Dim sound As String = "D:\BINGO BONANZA\FILIPINO\" + lblletter.Text + " " + lblNumber.Text + ".wav"
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(sound) Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(sound, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    Else
        MsgBox("No sound file for this")
    End If
   End If
 End Sub
```

If the first condition is not met than it will execute the else... Give this a try and let me know if it works for you. Also set a break point on the "Private Sub sound" and press "F11" to step through and check your conditions...

Answer (score 0):

You know whats wrong now, for your convenience here is a slightly more concise and othadox way to code it:

```
Private Sub PlaySound()

 If (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblletter.Text) Or string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblNumber.Text)) Then return

 Dim soundFile As String = String.Format("D:\BINGO BONANZA\{0}\{1} {2}.wav",lbllang.Text, lblletter.Text, lblNumber.Text)

 If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(soundFile) Then
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(soundFile, AudioPlayMode.Background)
 Else
    MessageBox.Show("No sound found for file: " & soundFile)
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved my problem.. It doesn't have to do anything with my codes. The language passed on sometimes doesn't get a value. Thanks for your time anyway.. :)